# PHP and SQL Server returns no rows with ™ in field

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, sqlsrv

I'm having a problem with the query it works fine in SQL server but when I trying to return the row in PHP it comes back without any results. See the code below the issue is with this field SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.ItemCodeDesc this field is exactly what it sounds like it's an item description and on this particular record it has this data in it. **ACC, Smart-Trek™ Deluxe Stereo**

I have confirmed this is the issue ™ for some reason this field will not display in PHP. I could edit the data although I would like to reserved that option for a last ditch effort. I'm not sure why this particular data is stopping all information from being returned. I don't get a PHP error. Any help would be most welcome much appreciated.

```
$tsql = "
   SELECT 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader.CustomerNo, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader.CustomerPONo, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.SalesOrderNo, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.CancelledLine, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.ItemCode, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.ItemCodeDesc, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.QuantityBackordered, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.QuantityOrderedRevised, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.PurchaseOrderNo, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.QuantityShipped, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader.OrderStatus, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader.OrderDate, 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader.CustomerPONo 
   FROM SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail 
   INNER JOIN SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader ON 
      SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.SalesOrderNo = SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader.SalesOrderNo 
   WHERE 
      (SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader.CustomerNo = 'XXXXXXX') AND 
      (SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader.OrderStatus <> 'X') AND 
      (SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.CancelledLine = 'N') AND 
      (SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader.CustomerPONo = 'XXXXXXX')
";

$getResults= sqlsrv_query($connms, $tsql);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults);
```

Comment: See if it is actually stored as `&trade;` or **`™`**. And what do you mean _"for some reason this field will not display in PHP"_ it just does't display **`™`**?

Comment: No I should have said nothing it returned. No record at all.

Comment: How do I find this out? See if it is actually stored as &trade; or ™.

Comment: Your question and the query appear to have nothing to do with each other. Nothing in your query is looking for the ™ character, meaning that the query is returning no results because nothing is returning true in the `WHERE`.If the `WHERE` isn't true, then it doesn't matter if one of the other columns has  `™` in it; it's completely unrealted.

Comment: Several ways.  Select a row that you know has a TM by some other criteria like `SELECT ItemCodeDesc FROM SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail WHERE id = 100` echo it and view the source of the webpage.

Comment: When I look at the table this field is a varchar(30) and when I cut a paste it it comes out as ™

Comment: @RickVenuto it can't be a `varchar` and store ™. `SELECT '™'` will return `?` as it isn't recognised ANSI character. Unless you're using a UTF-8 collation is SQL Server 2019?

Comment: The query works fine and returns a row if I do it in SQL management studio but when I run the same exact query in PHP it does not return a row. If I take ™ out of the field and re-run the query it returns the row.  So I'm fairly sure that ™ is the reason is not returning a row.

Comment: I know very little about MS SQL Server so I'll let others flesh it out.

Comment: Then provide us an [mre]. Nothing on your query even mentions the character, so the query you've supplied isn't the problem.

Comment: The field name is not ™ that is part of the data in the field.

Comment: *What* column..? Like I said, give us an [mre].

Comment: I agree the query is not the problem if it was it would not work in SQL management studio it has to do with PHP I would think.

Comment: In my original question I stated this was the column or field SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.ItemCodeDesc

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I thought I'd pass it along to help others. It can be found at the URL below.

Add this for your connection configuration array: `"CharacterSet" =>"UTF-8"`.

For example:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBName", "CharacterSet" =>"UTF-8" );
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brian_swan/sql-server-driver-for-php-connection-options-characterset